# Saving my marks so that when I close the file it will reopen it in VsVim

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I'm using VsVim in visual studio community
when I set a mark like `mA` in a file, after closing that file I can't reopen it
by using `` \`A `` or `'A`
even when I wrote the `:set viminfo='1000,f1` in my .vimrc file nothing changed.
is there a way to save these marks ?

Comment: Does VsVim actually read the `.vimrc` file? I don't think it supports the full range of Vim commands, so reading Vim's configuration would be bad. I'd rather expect a separate configuration file...

Comment: it reads the .vimrc file but it doesn't work about this case it seems.